# Merging Two ObservableCollections

Tags: .net, observablecollection

I have two Observable Collections that I need to merge into one collection.

This arises because I have two methods, getTasks(staffID) which returns an ObservableCollection and getTasks(teamID) which selects the staff and pulls back the staff tasks.

For the teams I will have multiple small observableCollections, I just want to merge them.

Comment: "I just want to _merge_ them" - does that mean that you have to take care of duplicates? Or does a simple concatenation suffice? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx

Comment: I was not concerned with duplicates. However I've gone down the path of Union<>  which is similar but provides for other design features; there is a shared task system. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This is what worked for me:

Concat or Union, but the result is a IEnumerable, so it needs to be converted back into an ObservableCollection:

```
var result = new ObservableCollection<T>(list1.Concat(list2));
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a reference to [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) on another SO article: [Merged ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777048/merged-observablecollection)

Since you're looking to do a Concat/Union, this seems to do exactly that.  Too bad it's not strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

I went with volkerK's suggestion and then moved to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx
Ta