# CompositeCollection + CollectionContainer: Bind CollectionContainer.Collection to property of ViewModel that is used as DataTemplates DataType

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate, compositecollection

I do not get the correct Binding syntax to access the `Cats` and `Dogs` properties of `MyViewModel` within a `DateTemplate` that defines a `CompositeCollection` within its resources.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Cat> Cats { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Dog> Dogs { get; private set; }
}
```

```xml
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
  <DataTemplate.Resources>
    <CompositeCollection x:Key="MyColl">
      <!-- How can I reference the Cats and Dogs properties of MyViewModel? -->
      <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Dogs, ????}">
      <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Cats, ????}">
    </CompositeCollection>
  </DataTemplate.Resources>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyColl}">
    <!-- ... -->
  </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

What do I have to insert for ???? to bind the `Dogs` and `Cats` collections to the `CollectionContainer`s?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Due to the issue with data binding on `CollectionContainer` as described http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b15cbd9d-95aa-47c6-8068-7ae9f7dca88a/collectioncontainer-does-not-support-relativesource?forum=wpf I now use the following approach:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DogCollection" Source="{Binding Dogs}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CatCollection" Source="{Binding Cats}"/>
  </ListBox.Resources>
  <ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
      <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource DogCollection}}"/>
      <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CatCollection}}"/>
    </CompositeCollection>
  </ListBox.ItemsSource>
  <!-- ... -->
</ListBox>
```

**Edit:** The `CompositeCollection` class does not derive from `FrameworkElement` and thus does not have a `DataContext` property to support data binding. It will only work if you use `Binding` providing a `Source`. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6446923/1254795 for more information.

Comment: This works great for me. But it would be more helpful if you could explain _why_ this is required. I don't understand: **1)** why can't I declare a `CollectionContainer` resource the same way and use it directly, instead of indirecting through the `CollectionViewSource`? and **2)** why can't I declare a `CompositeCollection` as a resource and just bind to `CollectionContainer` objects within directly? What is so special about `CollectionViewSource` that it works here even when other types won't?

Answer (score 4):

Try giving your `ListBox` a name and refer to its `DataContext` in the bindings:

```
<ListBox x:Name="myList" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource MyColl}">
   <ListBox.Resources>
      <CompositeCollection x:Key="MyColl">
         <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.Dogs, Source={x:Reference myList}}"/>
         <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.Cats, Source={x:Reference myList}}"/>
      </CompositeCollection>
   </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This does not work. I get an exception that the name of the `ListBox` can not be resolved. I think this is due to the fact that the `CompositeCollection` is declared within `DataTemplate.Resources` and the `ListBox` is declared after.

Comment: just a suggestion.. why do you want collection in template resources.. can you move this in ListBox resources?

Comment: If I move the `CompositeCollection` to `ListBox.Resources` then how I can reference it as `ListBox.ItemsSource`?

Comment: instead of StaticResource use `{DynamicResource MyColl}`

Comment: Circular reference: This problem occurs if you use `x:Reference` within the element you want to reference. This post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446699/how-do-you-bind-a-collectioncontainer-to-a-collection-in-a-view-model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446699/how-do-you-bind-a-collectioncontainer-to-a-collection-in-a-view-model) describes this problem too. It says that you have to move the `CompositeCollection` to the resources and use `StaticResource` - what I tried. But then I don't know how to bind the `CollectionContainer` to the ViewModel properties. Circular problem ;-)

Comment: it wont give the cyclical error in case you put collectin in your listbox resources and use dynamicresource to refer it... just tested this... working fine.. updated the answer with the tested code

Comment: Can you give me a code sample for this? I tried it and it did not work.

Comment: This does not work, brings me an XamlParseException: Cannot call MarkupExtension.ProvideValue because of a cyclical dependency. Properties inside a MarkupExtension cannot reference objects that reference the result of the MarkupExtension. 
The affected MarkupExtensions are: System.Windows.Data.Binding

Comment: This works fine for me. However, the XAML editor complains with a `NullReferenceException` (i.e. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"). It works fine at runtime, but the editor error is annoying; any way to declare this in a way that won't result in the editor error?

Comment: @Oliver You can in fact also reference the collection using `StaticResource`, but because of the sequential processing of XAML, you have to specify the `ItemsSource` after the `<ListBox.Resources>` section for it to work. e.g.: `<ListBox.ItemsSource><StaticResource ResourceKey="MyColl"/></ListBox.ItemsSource>`.