# How to implement a Custom ItemsControl with pre-built items?

Tags: wpf

I want to create a custom control that acts like a `ToolBar` control but contains pre-built elements in addition to those provided by the user.

As an example, with the code below I need a tool bar that contains predefined elements then the two user provided buttons:

```xml
<MyToolBar>
    <Button>User button 1</Button>
    <Button>User button 2</Button>
</MyToolBar>
```

Which would then be equivalent to:

```xml
<ToolBar>
    <Button>Predefined button 1</Button>
    <Button>Predefined button 2</Button>
    <Button>User button 1</Button>
    <Button>User button 2</Button>
</ToolBar>
```

I have tried inheriting `ToolBar` class and specify a `CompositeCollection` as `ToolBar.ItemSource`, however it fails, throwing

> Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element

```xml
<!-- Wrong Code -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyToolBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyToolBar}">
                <ToolBar>
                    <ToolBar.ItemsSource>
                        <CompositeCollection>
                            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding ItemsSource,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                            <Button>Predefined button 1</Button>
                            <Button>Predefined button 2</Button>
                        </CompositeCollection>
                    </ToolBar.ItemsSource>
                </ToolBar>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: @Orace User means developers using the custom control

Comment: @Orace That's great! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a read-only [collection-type dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/collection-type-dependency-properties?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) and add the default items to it in your class:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(ItemsSource))]
public class MyToolBar : Control
{
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey s_itemsSourcePropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
          name: nameof(ItemsSource),
          propertyType: typeof(List<FrameworkElement>),
          ownerType: typeof(MyToolBar),
          typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
        );

    public MyToolBar()
    {
        SetValue(s_itemsSourcePropertyKey, new List<FrameworkElement>()
        {
            new Button(){ Content = "Predefined button 1" },
            new Button(){ Content = "Predefined button 2" }
        });
    }

    public List<FrameworkElement> ItemsSource =>
        (List<FrameworkElement>)GetValue(s_itemsSourcePropertyKey.DependencyProperty);
}
```

**Template:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyToolBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyToolBar}">
                <ToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MyToolBar}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Usage:**

```
<local:MyToolBar>
    <Button>User button 1</Button>
    <Button>User button 2</Button>
</local:MyToolBar>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243109), it appear that the binding on `CollectionContainer.Collection` do not update the container content when the source content change.
You have to use a `CollectionViewSource` has a proxy:

```xml
<Style x:Key="MyToolBarStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
                <ToolBar>
                    <ToolBar.Resources>
                        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="TemplateItems" Source="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" />
                    </ToolBar.Resources>
                    <ToolBar.ItemsSource>
                        <CompositeCollection>
                            <Button>Predefined button 1</Button>
                            <Button>Predefined button 2</Button>
                            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource TemplateItems}}" />
                        </CompositeCollection>
                    </ToolBar.ItemsSource>
                </ToolBar>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```